# li rel= selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Please help selecting **rel="28700"** to change the `<li>` text:

```
<li id="pen_li_8" rel="28700"><span class="linkselectValue">Text to be changed</span></li>
```

I've tried the obvious:

```
$("li[rel='28700']").text('new text');
```

to no avail. Any ideas?

P.S. Sadly, selecting the ID or class, or editing the HTML, is not an option.

Comment: People need to stop putting `rel` attributes on everything and using them for arbitrary data... o_O

Comment: haha agreed this is a plugin , seems to over complicate things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is invalid, for one thing - you're missing a closing `]`. Also, if you want to change the text in the `<span>`, you need to select that, too. Here's the selector you want:

```
$('li[rel=28700] span').text('new text');
```